# dynamic threshold

Tags: opencv

In my application i have a problem and don't know how to implement my idea in opencv. Could Anone please direct me how to sort out this issue. i want a dynamic threshold based on hue-sat color so that i can identify specific locations in an image. following are the threshold values that work fine for different images

```
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(5, 70, 179), cvScalar(54, 255, 255), imgThreshed); // work fine for img1, img2 and img3 but not for img4, img5, img6.

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(5, 100, 100), cvScalar(54, 255, 255), imgThreshed); //work fine for img4, img5 but nor for img1,2,3 and 6

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(5, 96, 140), cvScalar(100, 255, 255), imgThreshed);// work fine img7 but not for img 1,2,3,4,5,6.

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(5, 100, 100), cvScalar(35, 255, 255), imgThreshed);

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(12, 63 , 128), cvScalar(18, 200, 255), imgThreshed);

cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(5, 70, 160), cvScalar(100, 255, 255), imgThreshed);
```

I need a generalize approach so that  max and min hue-sat value can can be extracted and put in cvInranges() during run time. so far i studied i found that there is a histogram that can be used to determine hue-sat of the image. could you please guide me or refer me how to get hue-sat maximum and minimum value of specific region during run time so that i can generalize my application in opencv. If anyone has any other idea I WOULD BE REALLY VERY THANKFUL TO YOU. i am stuck at that point.

Comment: Are you trying to find 2 pixels in your imgHSV - one with maximum (Hue-Sat) HS values and the other with minimum HS values? But how do you define the max and min of two pairs of values? Do you want the one with max and min sum of HS? i.e. for each pixel, sum their H and S then find the max and min?

Comment: no, jsut range of a color space, i might dint explain properly so explanation in own answer section